# how to get not matching records from same tables in sql?

Tags: sql

Suppose i have one table contain two country one is US and another is CO, for US country i have 141 records and for CO country i have 85, i need a query to find the unmatched record from both country

Comment: Unmatched to what? Do you mean that you want to find records which are not from either US or CO? In that case you can simply set a WHERE clause for country != US AND country != CO.

Comment: Thanks for replying, Suppose for US country i have 141 records and for CO country i have 85, So i want remaining records i.e 141-85= 56. how i will find these remaining records.

Comment: Please provide sample data and table structure

Comment: @Fahim Watch on the `null` values in country column.

Comment: @StefanoZanini, Same table i have 2 columns one for US country that contain 141 records and other columns for CO country contain 85 records.

Comment: Please define what you expect with a "matched" record and an "unmatched" record using sample data.

Comment: Please **[EDIT]** your question and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: Also: which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this might work

```
select c1.US
from country c1 left outer join country c2
on c1.US = c2.CO
where c2.CO is null;
```